# Developing universal in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, xcode6

I have Xcode 6 beta installed and I'm trying to develop an universal app. Before Xcode 6, you had to create 2 separate Storyboards for iPad and iPhone and you could set it in the Deployment Info.

[image]

In Xcode 6, it seems that separation is gone. There aren't 2 tabs to set the storyboards individually.

[image]

**But** when you go to create a Storyboard, you are asked to choose a device family.

[image]

Can someone explain what's going on in Xcode 6 please?

Thank you.

Comment: someone asked the same question before, and it was answered on WWDC as not a bug, but as structural changes in Xcode. you can find more information under the _Unified Storyboard for Universal Apps_ section: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To support the new Size Classes, you'll need to enable "Use Size Classes" in the File Inspector of your storyboard. This will allow you to configure your storyboard for multiple device sizes.

Note that this will make your storyboard incompatible with Xcode 5.

[image: Use Size Classes Xcode]

When you've enabled this, you'll see the size selector appear at the bottom of the screen. Use this to select your device size:

[image: Size Selector]

In your project preferences, you can still select a different storyboard for iPhone or iPad using the dropbown box. Notice that the storyboard name will persist if you select a different one for each device.

[image: Device Selection]

Even though this is still an option, Apple is moving developers towards a single, unified storyboard.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks. Perfect timing because I was laying off of this issue for a while due to the lack of information regarding this and I just started to see if I can get my head around this new size classes thing.

Comment: Hey Mike, i have a issue when using the universal storyboards for iPhone and iPad both. i have designed the application for iPad and iPhone using the different size classes as available in Xcode6. but now when i connect the outlet of a label to iPhone design and then to iPad design the outlet got disconnected from previous one. can you tell me whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Auto layout is used to support all devices now, yet you can create separate storyboards?  Have you tried calling the separate storyboards in code in the app delegate

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       //Use iPhone Storyboard

     } else {

       //Use iPad Storyboard
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

After **Xcode 6** **>** version for using `different storyboard for iPhone and iPad` need to follow [xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone](https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/)

**Note** : For **Application** which **does not use** **Auto Layout**, so while adding new storyboard for iPad and disabling auto layout, a pop will appear that's where you need **keep size class data to iPad** as shown in below screen.

[image]