# Convert from iPhone storyboard to size class xcode 6

Tags: class, size

I want to upgrade my iPhone app as soon as possible to a single universal storyboard to be ready with it when the new iPhones are on the market.

I checked "use Size Classes" but the size of my View Controllers are still 320 x 568 how can I change the size to 480 x 640 (wAny hRegular) by example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developing universal in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080493/developing-universal-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

1.) Locate your .storyboard, highlight it
2.) Enable Use Size Classes checkbox in the File Inspector

done!

Under Deployment Info
I also changed Devices to Universal

-> Copy MainStoryboard to use main iPad interface -> copy

Answer (score 0):

just open your project in to Xcode6 .
after open inspector element and just check size classes and you can get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that checking the "use Size Classes" converted most of the storyboards, but some of them remained 320x568 which is only for the iPhone 5.  It turned out that the Simulated Size had been set to Freeform in the Size Inspector.

Once the Simulated Size was switched to Fixed, that Storyboard switched to the Universal Size.