# Universal Application in Xcode 6 compatibility with iOS6/7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, compatibility, universal

I'm developing an universal application using Xcode 6.0.1 universal storyboards. Xcode generated for me one storyboard that will be used for both iPhone and iPad. To get this worked I must use size classes.

So my questions are :

1. If I use size classes, my application will be compatible for iOS6 and iOS7?
2. If not, what is the solution to make it compatible with iOS6 and iOS7, using Xcode6?

[I found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080493/developing-universal-in-xcode-6)

But it didn't explain the compatibility of the universal application in iOS6/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **will be** compatible with iOS7 for sure. Have not tried it with iOS6. It's easy to try - if you already have a project - just run in iOS6 simulator and see if it works (I suspect it will)

The only one caveat - you still need to use launch images for pre iOS8 versions. Launch xib file will work only for iOS8. So in your case I would recommend to use both image and xib file.