# I developed an app only on IPhone now i want the same app universal, is there any way to transform it on Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I tried it in build settings but its not working, images are not getting bigger in iPad they are looking small and almost same as iPhone display, its working perfectly on all iPhone devices, where as it displaying small on IPads, any solutions to solve this problem, please help me, advance thanks for every one

Comment: You need to make different storyboard for both and different images also.

Comment: you try and set Autoresizing...

Comment: @Blackbird i tried auto resizing and added constraints as well no use.

Comment: @pramod yeah i can do that but any other option for using single storyboard

Comment: than create a new storyboard for iPad. not perfection in design in singal storyboard

Comment: @Sandpie vary complicated in one storyboard.

Comment: @Sandpie vary easy to manage two storyboard .

Comment: @Pramod thank you i think using two storyboards will solve the problem

Comment: @BlackbirdSR-71 thank you mate

Comment: @Sandpie welcome bro,,,

Comment: @Sandpie most welcome bro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have the same UI for iPad then you don't need to do anything if you're supporting iPhone 4 device support for your app. As any app supports iPhone 4 can smoothly runs on iPad device as well. However, if you have a separate design then you required to take a separate storyboard for your iPad design everything as per the requirement. With Xcode 6, Apple introduced size classes which made easy to develop an universal app too.

I would like to add some links that should guide you to start.

[Developing universal in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080493/developing-universal-in-xcode-6)

**Other Links:**

[Universal App Link 1](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Size_Classes_to_Design_Universal_iOS_User_Interfaces)
| [Universal App Link 2](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/)
 | [Universal App Link 3](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/using-auto-layout-in-xcode-6-for-universal-ios-app-development/)
| [Universal App Link 4](https://irawd.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/xcode-6-separate-storyboard-for-ipad-and-iphone/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i will check out the links